# How to check DateTime value if it has a chosen value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where users can search for data from & till some specific date. The problem is where there isn't a specific date, the page should load all records, in my case I'm not sure how can I check if the search(DateTime)is 'null'. It's returning `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`, should I convert it into a string and check if the string matches this date? What is the best partice?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Invoices(string Notification, SearchDateModel search)
{
    var invoices = _invoiceService.GetAllInvoices();
    ViewBag.Notification = Notification;

    var ModelData = new InvoiceDataModel();

    if (search != null)
    {
        var foundInvoces = _invoiceService.SearchForInvoices(search.From, search.Till);
        ModelData.List = foundInvoces.Select(x => x.ToModel()).ToList();

        return View(ModelData);
    }
    else
    {
        if (invoices != null)
        {
            ModelData.List = invoices.Select(x => x.ToModel()).ToList();

            return View(ModelData);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a date time variable which is not assigned  then you need check if the variable has DateTime.MinValue or not.

```
//Date Time Variable
DateTime datetime = new DateTime();
//Check if datetime variable is having the MinValue or not
if (datetime == DateTime.MinValue) {
//DateTime is null
}
```

Comment: I suspect it'll never change, but it might be better to use `default(DateTime)` instead. It is the same as `DateTime.MinValue`, but it does more clearly express that it is a default value.